# Cursorline only highlights textwidth not entire window

Tags: vim

I like to edit my code in fullscreen and like a visual hint what the textwidth is. I have the text that is passed the 79 characters highlighted using `OverLength`. I created another visual indicator by setting the `ColorColumn` to `+1`. Instead of the `ColorColumn`, I would prefer if the `CursorLine` only highlighted the portion of the line is the `textwidth` rather than the entire line, i.e. `CursorLine` stops after 79 characters. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no way to change what the `CursorLine` highlight group covers.

Answer (score 1):

`CursorLine` always covers the entire width of the current window (multiple lines if `'wrap'` is set), regardless of the actual length of the line. The length also cannot be influenced by any built-in option. Same applies to `CursorColumn` in the vertical direction.

The recommended way to highlight a certain text width is via `ColorColumn`.